# How to hide database info in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cpanel

I have a virtual hosting server which can handle some static html files:

```
+-- public_ftp
+-- temp
+-- logs
+-- mail
...
+-- public_html
    +-- www
        +-- index.html
    +-- blog
        +-- index.html
```

which `www` folder handle `www.mydomain.com` and `blog` folder handle `blog.mydomain.com`. The hosting server is running with `cPanel`. 
I write my website using react, and `npm run build` to get the result, and put everything into www folder, it works fine. Now my react need query some info from mysql database. Is there any good way to query database in react and hide the username and password from the user? I can encode the final js files that from the build script but it seems strange. 
I can also write express to handle some request from react. However, what should I do so that I can put express code into the hosting server? where should I put? should I create `api` folder under `public_html` and send the request using `api.mydomain.com`? I use `localhost` and different ports in the development env and I don't know how ports works in the production env. I think change everything from `localhost:8000` to `api.mydomain.com` at last is a bad idea. Can I still use localhost in the hosting server? Can I write express inside react folder or write react in express folder therefore I can run build script one time to pack both frond and backend side? If I upload server code into somewhere, will the user have the ability to see the server code?

Comment: Never ever hard code secrets in your file. Not even when you compile it to binary as those can be found with hex editor.  Somewhat better is using environment variables. Still not perfect though. This is a very complex and delicate topic.

Comment: To your second question you are on the right track somewhat. You would write a backend service, likely a `JSON API` that does `CRUD` on the database. Such an API would probably not be hosted with cpanel as its not static content. Such a service would be run directly by the node runtime and listen on a port that you can choose. Then you can make requests to that port either on localhost, if they are on the same host or via ip address or dns name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never connect your database and make queries directly at your front-end, but you can make an express api like you've said with the "api" subdomain.

I think this tutorial of how to deploy a node.js server at cPanel can help you with other questions: https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-with

If both, react and node.js, are running at the same host ip address, you can still use localhost to communicate with the back-end, otherwise just use the api subdomain and it will work just fine.

Also don't worry, the user will not be able to see your server side code.

Edit:
You can also use Fastify like The Fool suggested at the comments, use any framework you like, that's just an example.

Comment: Its 2021, I would not recommend express these days. Fastify for example is much better.